# Binding web devexpress dxDataGrid and angular $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datagrid, devexpress

I am having issues with binding $scope in angular and dxDataGrid.

I'm using devexpress libarary dx.all.js which provides the dxDataGrid with all its goodies.  I have a div dx-data-grid and trying to pass the selected row data onto the $scope.

Chrome debuger says that it is null both my $scope.ticketSelected variable and the selectedRowsData object. here is the API
http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Events/?version=14_2#selectionChanged

HTML CODE is

Angular Code is

```
    controller('homeController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
        $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
        $scope.ticketSelected = [];     
        $scope.items = [];
$scope.random = function() {
            var s = 55;
            s = Math.sin(s) * 10000;
            s = s - Math.floor(s);
            return s;
        };

    $scope.generateData = function (count) {
        $scope.items = [];
        var i,item;
        var names = ['James', 'John', 'Robert', 'Christopher', 'George', 'Mary', 'Nancy', 'Sandra', 'Michelle', 'Betty'];
        var company = ['MGPI', 'L & T'];
        var floor = ['GF', 'FF'];
        var bldg = ['S', 'P'];
        var startBirthDate = Date.parse('1/1/1975');
        var endBirthDate = Date.parse('1/1/1992');

        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            $scope.random();
            var insertDate = new Date(startBirthDate + Math.floor($scope.random() * 
                    (endBirthDate - startBirthDate)));
            //insertDate.setHours(12);

            $scope.random();
            var nameIndex = 
                Math.floor($scope.random() * names.length);
            item = {
                wkonum: i + 1,
                requester: names[nameIndex],
                company: company[Math.floor(nameIndex / 5)],
                floor: company[Math.floor(nameIndex / 5)],
                bldg: company[Math.floor(nameIndex / 5)],
                insertDate: insertDate
            };
            $scope.items.push(item);
        }
    };

    $scope.generateData(5000);

    $scope.gridOptions = {
            bindingOptions: {
                dataSource: 'items'//generateData(1000)
            },
            hoverStateEnabled: true,
            paging: {
                enabled: true,
                pageSize:10
            },
            /*editing: {
                editMode: 'row',
                editEnabled: true,
                removeEnabled: true,
                insertEnabled: true,
                removeConfirmMessage: 'Are you sure you want to delete this record?'
            },*/
            selection: {
                mode: 'single'
            },
            customizeColumns: function (columns) {
                columns[0].width = 80;
                columns[1].width = 100;
            },
            onSelectionChange:function(selecteditems){
                $scope.ticketSelected = selecteditems.selectedRowsData;             

            },
            columns: [
                    'wkonum',
                    'requester',
                    'company',
                    'floor',
                    'bldg',
                    'insertDate'
            ]     
        };
```

}).

Comment: here are the libraries used jquery-2.1.3.min.js angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js        angularjs/1.3.11/angular-sanitize.js  globalize/0.1.1/globalize.min.js

Answer (score 0):

I came to the conclusion The onSelectionChange was not firing. I used onRowClick instead and used the $scope directly it worked like a charm.

I'm not sure i know why the onSelectionChange did not work, but the onRowClick does it for now.
http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/?version=14_2#onRowClick

```js
onRowClick:function(e){
  $scope.ticketSelected = e.data; 
},
```

Answer (score 0):

actually the event is not "onSelectionChange" it is "onSelectionChanged"

Answer (score 0):

"onSelectionChanged" works only when selection mode is 'multiple', not single.